# Meteor Iron router prepend '#!' to my URL

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When I use Meteor Iron router. Except the root domain, there is a `#!` at all the other destination URL.

Example:
When I visit http://example.com/blog the url show in my browser will become http://example.com/#!blog
Seems there is a weird redirection happening in background.

Comment: What browser are you using? I think IR defaults to using some form of hashbangs when you are viewing it in a non html5 browser, the code that does this is in the iron:location package somewhere

Comment: I use chrome but it also happen in safari and firefox

Comment: Ah well it was worth a check :)